# Is it possible to overload lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, mapping, overloading

I have the following expression that does some entity(entityframework) to business object mapping

```
internal static Expression<Func<CardholderEntity, Cardholder>> ExpressionMap = entity => new Cardholder
{
    Id = entity.Id,
    CardholderNo = entity.CardholderNo,
};
```

However, when I create another lambda expression like this with different parameters:

```
internal static Expression<Func<AnotherCardholderEntity, Cardholder>> ExpressionMap = entity => new Cardholder
{
    Id = entity.AnotherId,
    CardholderNo = entity.AnotherCardholderNo,
};
```

I get a red underline under ExpressionMap saying `member with same name already declared`

Is it possible, or are there any work arounds to this?

Assuming I have hundreds of expression mappings of different entities to business objects, I wouldn't want to have to come up with that many different names for each of them

Comment: No, it is not. This is because lambda calls are *not* dispatched like methods; the lambda (or expression) is a single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with lambdas. What you're doing is essentially the equivalent of:

```
internal static int x = 5;
internal static string x = "five";
```

Which obviously wouldn't work.

You could even get rid of the lambdas and it would still not work:

```
internal static Expression<Func<CardholderEntity, Cardholder>> ExpressionMap = null;
internal static Expression<Func<AnotherCardholderEntity, Cardholder>> ExpressionMap = null;
```

The solution kind of depends on the architecture of your application and what your goals are. But one option would be to keep a dictionary of them based on the type. Not sure if that will work for you, though.